# Does it makes sense to queue send operations when using Socket.SendAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

I am using .NET async send method (SendAsync) from Socket class. Do I need to queue send operations in order to send the payload over the wire one by one after the previous transmission finishes?

I've noticed that SendAsync will accept happily any bytes I throw at it without complaining that the previous send has finished or not. The protocol I am using deals with out-of-order messages.

Does the Windows socket stack already do queuing internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Socket-class should do this internaly - if you check the return value [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendasync.aspx):
Returns true if the I/O operation is pending.
Returns false if the I/O operation completed synchronously.